# ModelandView 404 Problem

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I can't realize why do I have 404 error while trying to access /liginform.dlp through POST method

I have the following web.xml mapping:

```
  <servlet-name>doolloop</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>doolloop</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.dlp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>doolloop</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.dlp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.dlp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

doolloop-servlet.xml looks like this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.doolloop.controllers" />
<bean id="viewResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix">
<value>/</value>
</property>
<property name="suffix">
<value>.jsp</value>
</property>
</bean>
```

I have two jsp pages
 /index.jsp
 /forms/loginform.jsp

The controllers looks lke this:

```
@Controller
public class DoolloopController{
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @RequestMapping("/index.dlp")
    public ModelAndView index(){
        logger.info("Return View");
        return new ModelAndView("index");
    }
```

The following code brings 404 error:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/loginform.dlp",method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView CheckLogin(){
            ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/form/loginform");
            return mv;
        }
```

If I change it to the following way it works perfectly:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/loginform.dlp",method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String showForm() {
                return "/forms/loginform";
```

what is the problem? please help

Comment: turn up logging for the `org.springframework.web` logger and Spring will output a whole lot of useful information about which classes and methods it is binding to which URL patterns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps your resolved JSP path starts with double slash (one from the `prefix` property and another from the returned value).

Answer (score 4):

Double check your imports. Make sure you use:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView
```

and not:

```
org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView.
```

The first one is for servlet and the later is for portlet.

Comment: This was my exact problem.